# How to add an image to github ReadMe.md file

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows, github-flavored-markdown

I have tries all the below and the image does not seems to be appearing on my read me file. I've added the image under the issues as someone suggested but nothing. also tried numerous other methods but the image does not want to appears and on the video tutorials i'm doing line by line but nothing.

**link to the isssues:**
`https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/89415628/185356092-4229772b-1852-4ee0-9daa-043ff87a2080.png`

**using the img tag with the image that are in the root folder**
 `<img src="https://github.com/Opzalas/CMPG-323-Overview---33448809/blob/main/branching.png?raw=true">`

**The most used method to add image to read me file with image under the issues**
`![](https://github.com/Opzalas/CMPG-323-Overview---33448809/blob/main/assets/images/89415628/185356092-4229772b-1852-4ee0-9daa-043ff87a2080.png?raw=true)`

**image stored on the root repo with image link**
`![](https://github.com/Opzalas/CMPG-323-Overview---33448809/blob/main/branching.png)`

** Image with the root directory**
`![](branching.png)`

What is funny is that it is working within stack overflow but not on github with the img tag with root directory.

Comment: I took a look at your file, and the problem is that your text blocks are indented. In Markdown, that means "code block", where everything is interpreted literally. You have to un-indent them. I have created a [PR](https://github.com/Opzalas/CMPG-323-Overview---33448809/pull/30) to show you how.

Comment: @ScottWelker The question is un-answerable as such, as the code shown doesn't have the same problems as the actual code found elsewhere. I'd be inclined to close as "not reproducible" unless edited.

Comment: @ScottWelker not sure how to mark this as answered.

Comment: @Opzalas. See Benjamin W.'s comments. Without an answer I don't believe you can mark the question answered. I defer now to Benjamin. He's given this more thought than I can.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided in [@Benjamin W's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73402221/how-to-add-an-image-to-github-readme-md-file/73482917#comment129626724_73402221); thank you, much appreciated. Please see answer below:

> I took a look at your file, and the problem is that your text blocks are indented. In Markdown, that means "code block", where everything is interpreted literally. You have to un-indent them. I have created a PR to show you how.